# Magento 2 : Issue with Paypal Payment from outside India

Tags: magento, paypal

My website is in Magento 2 with base currency and merchange set to INR and India.
I am able to pay from India, but my customer outside India are facing issue with payment they are getting some strange error like :

"We aren't able to process your payment using your PayPal account at this time. Please go back to merchant and try using a different payment method."

I have enabled all currencies on my account please help with way to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to enable this option in your PayPal Business account.

Go to *Settings* ➞ *My selling tools* ➞ *Block payments* section under *Getting paid and managing my risk*.

Click on Update and then select the option *Yes, accept and convert them to INR* under *Allow payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold*.

See this image for reference:

[image: Paypal settings]

Comment: in addition to this i have to change my base currency to usd to non indian customers